# How do i get Math Class's source?

Tags: c#, .net

I am just a bit interested in how the Math class is coded in C#. How do i get it all?

Comment: In addition to the Microsoft implementation, you can look at the implementation of Math.cs in the Mono project (www.mono-project.com). Methods marked "extern" probably eventually punt to standard C library math functions (contained in libm.so or something like that on Unix-like systems, not sure about Windows). You can also find the GNU implementation of libm in Glibc. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Comment: There is not much to see, many of its methods are either intrinsic processor instructions or is code in the C runtime library.  Code that Microsoft bought from Intel, they could not get a source distribution license.  Nothing you'd want to see either, this is hand-crafted SSE assembly code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, it's all right [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,a4407e67b9a5afad).

However, you'll notice that a number of the methods are `extern` methods, which get delegated via `MethodImpl[MethodImplOptions.InternalCall]` to lower-level functions that are implemented inside the CLR. Most programmers don't have to do that sort of thing, but these functions are very "close to the metal."

Comment: Firstly, that's not open source. Source code may be viewed but not copied. There are open source bits from MS elsewhere. Secondly, much there doesn't actually contain the relevant code, since they're internal to the CLR.

Comment: @hvd: Good catch. I was too loose with the term "open source."